# What is the PHP syntax for File/terminal output formatting?

Tags: php, file, command-line

I want to create a command line program using PHP. How do I design the program's I/O?
I can send output as text. I am wondering about the specific output syntax. For example: In HTML i use `<br/>` to pass to a new line. How can I do this using terminal/file output? Is there a reference for terminal/file oriented programming in PHP?

Comment: why the downvotes and vote to close? it seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. At least leave a constructive comment if you're going to vote to to close.

Comment: might have to do with the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/806521/list#rev47736447-ee23-4921-a29c-c49fed1dbc7d . still wondering how Yuval F managed to shape it so well.

Comment: might have to do with the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/806521/list#rev47736447-ee23-4921-a29c-c49fed1dbc7d . still wondering how Yuval F managed to shape it so well.

Comment: But still voting down and closing question instead of editing it is unreasonable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing command-line PHP scripts is quite simple, actually. You output text in the exact same way you would normally: `print` and `echo` both print text to the console. The only difference here is that you can't use HTML tags for formatting, since your code isn't being interpreted by a web browser (i.e. `"\n"` will actually create a visible line break, not `<br />`).

Reading input from stdin is a little trickier, but all it really involves is essentially using some of the file reading functions (e.g. `fgets()`, `fgetc()`, `fscanf()`) and passing in `STDIN` as the file path (or `php://stdin`, depending on how new your version of PHP is).

And yes, there is a [reference for command-line programming in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) on php.net. It covers pretty much everything you need to know to work with PHP in a command-line environment.

Answer (score 4):

When writing a CLI script consider ending lines with [PHP_EOL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) so it will be cross platform compatible with UNIX ( `\n` ), Windows ( `\n\r` ) and Mac ( `\r` ). And when you whant to print it as html use the PHP's [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.